# os.mknod returns [error38] function not implemented in google colab

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory, mknod

I am trying to run the following piece of code on google colab.

```
dir_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks'
log_loss_path =os.path.join(dir_path, 'log_loss.txt')
if not os.path.isfile(log_loss_path):
    os.mknod(log_loss_path)
```

but i get the error **[Errno 38] Function not implemented**

```
    OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-bd3880e6bb8b> in <module>()
      2 log_loss_path = os.path.join(dir_path, 'log_loss.txt')
      3 if not os.path.isfile(log_loss_path):
----> 4     os.mknod(log_loss_path)

OSError: [Errno 38] Function not implemented
```

can anyone help to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/content/drive` is a FUSE filesystem which doesn't support this operation.

If you are just trying to create a file, use instead `open(log_loss_path, 'w')`.